# Docker no suitable driver found sqlserver

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, docker

So I have a Spring boot application that runs on port 8080 on my localhost. It connects to an Azure sqlserver database and pulls or inserts item from that database. Locally everything is working fine. Now I'm trying to dockerize the application. My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8 AS build
COPY src /usr/src/app/src
COPY pom.xml /usr/src/app
COPY mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre15.jar .
RUN mvn -f /usr/src/app/pom.xml clean package

FROM gcr.io/distroless/java
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/target/ProfileService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/app/ProfileService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/usr/app/ProfileService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

The Dockerfile is located in the root folder, the same folder as the pom.xml and the mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre15.jar file. This jar is downloaded from the official Microsoft source. My pom includes multiple dependencies, one of them is the mssql-jdbc dependency.

```
<dependency>

    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>

    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>

    <version>9.2.1.jre15</version>

</dependency>
```

To connect to the database, I use the following code:

```
private final String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://x.database.windows.net:1433;DatabaseName=profile;user=x@xr;password=x;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;";
```

With the following method as an example to get data:

```
public GetProfileReturnModel getProfile(String profile_name) {
    GetProfileReturnModel returnModel = new GetProfileReturnModel();
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl)) {
        try {
            CallableStatement cstmnt = connection.prepareCall("{CALL getProfile(?)}");
            cstmnt.setString(1, profile_name);

            cstmnt.execute();
            ResultSet rs = cstmnt.getResultSet();
            if (rs.next()) {
                returnModel.setUser_id(rs.getInt("user_id"));
                returnModel.setBio(rs.getString("bio"));
                returnModel.setLocation(rs.getString("location"));
                returnModel.setProfile_name(rs.getString("profile_name"));
                returnModel.setPicture(rs.getString("picture"));
                returnModel.setWebsite(rs.getString("website"));
            }
            returnModel.setSuccess(true);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            returnModel.setSuccess(false);
            returnModel.setErrorMessage(e.toString());
    }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        returnModel.setErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
        returnModel.setSuccess(false);
    }
    return returnModel;
}
```

This works fine locally. But when I run my build image in Docker and I call the same request I get the following error:

> No suitable driver found for
> jdbc:sqlserver://x.database.windows.net:1433;DatabaseName=profile;user=x@xr;password=x;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;

There is also this weird behavior that when I run the packaged .jar file using the cmd it runs perfectly, but if I start it by double clicking the jar I get the same error as mentioned above

My complete pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.kwetter.profileservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProfileService</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>ProfileService</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>ProfileServiceBuild</id>
            <url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/382763/Kwetter/_packaging/ProfileServiceBuild/maven/v1</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>ProfileServiceBuild</id>
            <url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/382763/Kwetter/_packaging/ProfileServiceBuild/maven/v1</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.amqp/spring-rabbit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.amqp/spring-amqp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-amqp</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.1.jre15</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: If you have it in your POM like this you dont need to copy it manually in the image. It will be downloaded from maven central.

Comment: @RobertNiestroj that's what I thought. I just tried some stuff and that was one of them

Comment: Are you using `spring-boot-maven-plugin` ?

Comment: @michalk yes I am

Comment: How do you run your app locally? Through some IDE? Are you able to execute the jar file locally through commandline without an issue?

Comment: @michalk yea running through IntelliJ and cmd works fine. Double clicking the jar file doesn't work though

Comment: Please, can you share your `pom.xml` file in the question? It is not necessary to include all the dependencies, only those ones you consider appropriate, and your plugins.

Comment: @jccampanero I've added it in full

Comment: @KevinTinnemans I posted a possible solution, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `spring-boot-maven-plugin` should by default, when configuring a `jar` `packaging`, repackage and include all your project dependencies in a big jar when `mvn package` runs, so probably the SQL Server JDBC Driver related classes should be included as well.

The docker related problem may have to do with the fact that you are using an incompatible Java version for the provided SQL Server driver when running your application.

You are using the SQL Server JDBC Driver for Java 15:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
  <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>9.2.1.jre15</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Probably you are using Java 15 in your local environment, and it is running fine.

But you are running the application with `gcr.io/distroless/java` and that image only supports [Java 1.8 and Java 11](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/tree/main/java).

Please, consider use a [different version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc) of the SQL Server driver, for example:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
  <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>9.2.1.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

And adapt your Dockerfile if necessary:

```
FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8 AS build
COPY src /usr/src/app/src
COPY pom.xml /usr/src/app
RUN mvn -f /usr/src/app/pom.xml clean package

FROM gcr.io/distroless/java:8
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/target/ProfileService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/app/ProfileService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/usr/app/ProfileService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

I removed line `COPY mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.xxx.jar .`: if you are including the dependency in your pom it will not be necessary.

Perhaps the double click problem can also be related with this if you are using a different version of the JVM as the one configured by default in your OS.

Comment: Thank you so much. This did the trick! Even though I knew I had been messing around with java version, not once I thought it would be the reason why it didn't work. In 10 minutes I can give you your bounty

Comment: Hi @KevinTinnemans. You are very welcome. I am very happy to know that the answer was helpful and that you were able to solve the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by Azure SQL requiring login through AD Authentication.
Your connection string would look like this:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://x.database.windows.net:1433;DatabaseName=profile;user=x@xr;password=x;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword;
```

Comment: I don't think I've done anything with a Active Directory. Where should I find this password? Or is it the same password I use in my connection string to connect to the server?

Comment: You can find the connection string for this through the Azure portal.
Navigate to the Database -> Under settings go to "Connection Strings" -> Go to the JDBC tab and copy the "JDBC (Active Directory password authentication) one

Comment: I only have the SQL authentication connection string. Maybe this is because I have a student account?

Comment: If I look at the properties I can see that there is no active directory admin configured

Comment: Could be that the setup is different yes, I had a similar issue using my student account (Avans) and this solved that. But then it looks like your driver is not properly being loaded/referenced in the code

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are including the jdbc driver in your **build image** instead of your **runtime image**

You should copy it to your runtime images the following way : (please check the appropriate destination folder, but I assumed `/usr/app/`)

```
FROM gcr.io/distroless/java
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/target/ProfileService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/app/ProfileService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
COPY mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre15.jar /usr/app/
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/usr/app/ProfileService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```